# SSAS tuple error happening for non-admins

Tags: ssas

I have a large SSAS cube that started throwing the tuple error shown here a couple months ago. I couldn't figure out what was special about the way the cube was being queried that was causing the error but I found a (sad) workaround which was to make all users admins. Can anybody explain why the cube functions differently for admins??

[image: SSAS tuple error]

Comment: Do you have user specific permissions in the cube, like cell security or dimension security? When does the error occur? When accessing the cube, or when running queries? In specific queries or in all of them?

Comment: I took over management of the cube from somebody else so not sure about cell security and dimension security and they are grayed out in SSMS, do I need to look in Visual Studio? I was able to repro by using the measure with a big date range and few columns (there's only one measure in the cube).